# Left Outer Join with ON & AND & WHERE not working?

Tags: mysql, sql

The query to me looks perfectly ok but I'm still getting errors sadly:

```
SELECT s.id, s.uid, s.sexnumber, s.rating, s.sextime, w.who 
FROM users u, sex s 
LEFT OUTER JOIN who w 
JOIN whos ws ON s.id = ws.sid AND w.id=ws.wid 
WHERE u.sessionCheck='f9cf8142a10357d4d676f91e99a3242a' AND s.uid = u.uid 
GROUP BY s.id 
ORDER BY s.sextime ASC
```

With the following:

```
Native message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE
u.sessionCheck='f9cf8142a10357d4d676f91e99a3242a' AND s.uid = u.uid GROUP '
at line 1
```

As far as I am aware there is no problem using a `WHERE` with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Could there be another reason why this query doesn't work?

Comment: Very nice editing guys :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing old-style join syntax with the better join syntax.  Just say "no" to commas in the `from` clause.  I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT s.id, s.uid, s.sexnumber, s.rating, s.sextime, w.who 
FROM users u join
     sex s
     on s.uid = u.uid LEFT OUTER JOIN
     whos ws
     ON s.id = ws.sid LEFT OUTER JOIN
     who w 
     ON w.id=ws.wid 
WHERE u.sessionCheck = 'f9cf8142a10357d4d676f91e99a3242a'
GROUP BY s.id 
ORDER BY s.sextime ASC;
```

The problem with the `,` operator in MySQL is actually documented [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html), in terms of a change from an older version.

> Example:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE t1 (i1 INT, j1 INT);
> CREATE TABLE t2 (i2 INT, j2 INT);
> CREATE TABLE t3 (i3 INT, j3 INT);
> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1,1);
> INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(1,1);
> INSERT INTO t3 VALUES(1,1);
> SELECT * FROM t1, t2 JOIN t3 ON (t1.i1 = t3.i3);
> ```
>
> Previously, the SELECT was legal due to the implicit grouping of t1,t2
>   as (t1,t2). Now the JOIN takes precedence, so the operands for the ON
>   clause are t2 and t3. Because t1.i1 is not a column in either of the
>   operands, the result is an Unknown column 't1.i1' in 'on clause'
>   error. To allow the join to be processed, group the first two tables
>   explicitly with parentheses so that the operands for the ON clause are
>   (t1,t2) and t3:

```
SELECT * FROM (t1, t2) JOIN t3 ON (t1.i1 = t3.i3);
```

> Alternatively, avoid the use of the comma operator and use JOIN
>   instead:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 JOIN t3 ON (t1.i1 = t3.i3);
```

> This change also applies to statements that mix the comma operator
>   with INNER JOIN, CROSS JOIN, LEFT JOIN, and RIGHT JOIN, all of which
>   now have higher precedence than the comma operator.

Comment: O boy, got a lot to get my head round now :) Some very interesting things have changed from what I am used to. Dare I ask if this will improve performance? Not that my DB needs performance as its not live yet, but u know. Planning ahead and whatnot.

Comment: Having the correct use of `join` gives the optimizer a better chance of finding the right indexes to use.  In general, though, the performance is not necessarily better (or worse) with the proper syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the below line:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN who w JOIN whos ws ON s.id = ws.sid AND w.id=ws.wid
```

You have to change to:

```
JOIN whos ws ON s.id = ws.sid
LEFT OUTER JOIN who w ON w.id=ws.wid
```

Also you mixed the join syntax, it is suggested using the new join style only.

Comment: Nice one, query went through alright. But I think somehow the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` wasn't working correctly. I only got 3 results rather than the expected 60.